# Scala convert multi-layered json to multi-layered map

Tags: json, scala, dictionary, circe

I have a multi-layered map:

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.collection.mutable
import io.circe.Printer
import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.syntax._

var map = mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[String, mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]]]()
map.update("a", mutable.Map("b1" -> mutable.ArrayBuffer("c", "d", "e", "f")))
map("a").update("b2", mutable.ArrayBuffer("g", "h"))
```

and saved it in a file:

```
val json_path = "C:/myjason.json"
val json = map.asJson.pretty(Printer.spaces2)
var w: Writer = new FileWriter(json_path,false)
w.write(json)
w.close()
```

Now, I am trying to read the file back into my scala code and regenerate the map variable. I tried options below:

```
val json1 = Source.fromFile(json_path).getLines.mkString
val json2 = parse(json1.toString)
val json3 = decode[mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[String, ArrayBuffer[String]]]](json2.toString)
```

What I get are:

```
json1 is a string of "{"a" : {"b1" : ["c","d","e","f"], "b2" : ["g","h"]}}"
json2 is Right({"a" : {"b1" : ["c","d","e","f"], "b2" : ["g","h"]}})
json3 is io.circe.ParsingFailure: expected json value got 'Right(...' (line 1, column 1)
```

None of these are in the form of `HashMap` that I originally had. I appreciate it if you can advise me on how to convert it to the original `map` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
val json = Source.fromFile(json_path).getLines.mkString
val decoded_json = decode[mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[String, ArrayBuffer[String]]]](json.toString)
val map = decoded_json.right.get
```